# Firebase transferring data between pages

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a sign-up page that has a two-page process for a firebase based website. The first HTML page takes the users info (Name, email, etc.), the second lets them set some more data. I am having a problem when it comes to getting the unique user ID I set for the first page, transferring it over to the second page, and allowing the user to update their node with more data.

So I am using two separate js files the first for sign up page 1 is:

```
    var usersRef = firebase.database().ref().child('PickUp').child('Users').push();

    document.getElementById('mySubmit').addEventListener('click', submitForm);

    function submitForm(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var name = getInputVal('name');
        var pass = getInputVal('password');
        var email = getInputVal('emailfield2');
        var address = getInputVal('addressfield');
        var gender = getInputVal('gender');

        createUser( name, pass, email, address, gender);
       }

    function getInputVal(id){
        return document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
    function createUser(fullName, password, email, gender) {
    usersRef.set({
    fullname: fullName,
    password: password,
    email: email,
    gender: gender,
    karma: "5000",
    })
```

The Second is:

```
      var usersRef = firebase.database().ref().child('PickUp').child('Users');
  document.getElementById('mySubmit2').addEventListener('click', submitForm);
  function submitForm(e){

          e.preventDefault();

          var base = getInputVal('base');
          var basket = getInputVal('basket');
          var soccer = getInputVal('soccer');
          var tennis = getInputVal('tennis');
          var volley = getInputVal('volley');

          updateUser(base, basket, soccer, tennis, volley);
  }

  function updateUser(base, basket, soccer, tennis, volley) {
    usersRef.update({
        baseball: base,
        basketball: basket,
        tennis: tennis,
        soccer: soccer,
        volleyball: volley

    });
```

I am simply trying to connect these two nodes, from two different html pages, from two different files and make it 1 node with all the information in it.

I can't seem to find any references, or ways to fix this, but if there is please send it over. Any help is always appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `.onAuthStateChanged()` method included in the client side SDK - in your case, the JavaScript SDK, documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) is is how to do this. `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` will populate with that info.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a timing issue. It is possible that your second script invokes the `userRef` request 'too fast' for Firebase. What you can try to do is the following:

TL;DR - delay the Firebase user query

```
  var usersRef;
  document.getElementById('mySubmit2').addEventListener('click', submitForm);
  function submitForm(e){

          e.preventDefault();

          var base = getInputVal('base');
          var basket = getInputVal('basket');
          var soccer = getInputVal('soccer');
          var tennis = getInputVal('tennis');
          var volley = getInputVal('volley');
          userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('PickUp').child('Users');
          updateUser(base, basket, soccer, tennis, volley);
  }

  function updateUser(base, basket, soccer, tennis, volley) {
    usersRef.update({
        baseball: base,
        basketball: basket,
        tennis: tennis,
        soccer: soccer,
        volleyball: volley

    });
```